# Obtener los subdocumentos de una colección como salida de un búsqueda

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Estoy trabajando con meteor y MongoDB en un pequeño proyecto, he reemplazado una variable js que recibe diccionarios por una colección llamada Barra de Herramientas:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.startup(function () {
        if (Toolbars.find().count() == 0) {
            Toolbars.insert(
                {
                    name: 'main_toolbar',
                    title: 'Main toolbar',
                    items: [
                        {
                            name: 'Play buttons',
                            class: '',
                            help_text: '',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    name: 'Backward',
                                    class: 'backward',
                                    help_text: ''
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'Play',
                                    class: 'play'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'Forward',
                                    class: 'forward'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'name',
                                    class: 'stop'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Playback tools',
                            class: 'col-xs-12 col-md-3',
                            help_text: '',
                            items: [

                                {
                                    name: 'Playback progress',
                                    class: 'playback'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'Metronome',
                                    class: 'clock-o'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Tools',
                            class: '',
                            help_text: '',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    class: 'save'
                                },
                                {
                                    class: 'plus'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'View tools',
                            class: '',
                            help_text: '',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    class: 'search-plus'
                                },
                                {
                                    class: 'search-minus'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Sheet tools',
                            class: '',
                            help_text: '',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    class: 'hashtag'
                                },
                                {
                                    class: 'wrench'
                                },
                                {
                                    class: 'align-justify'
                                },
                                {
                                    class: 'arrows-alt'
                                }

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Info',
                            class: '',
                            help_text: '',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    class: 'info-circle'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            );
            console.log("startup.js says: " + Toolbars.find().count());
        }
    });

}
```

Requiero obtener de esa barra de herramientas todos los items como salida a la siquiente búsqueda:

```
Template.play_toolbar.helpers({
        // group: music_toolbar,
        group: Toolbars.find({name: 'main_toolbar'}, {items: 1}),
        ifProgressBar: function (name) {
            return name === 'playback'
        }
    });
```

Puesto que mi plantilla genera grupos de botones con la clase y nombre de cada elemento, y con cada subelemento genera los botones:

```
<template name="play_toolbar">
    {{#each group }}
        <div class="btn-group {{class}}" role="group" aria-label="{{name}}">
            {{#each items}}
                {{#if ifProgressBar class}}
                    {{> progress_bar}}
                {{else}}
                    <button class="btn btn-default {{class}}" title="{{name}}"><a class="fa fa-{{class}}"></a></button>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

El problema que tengo ahorita es que grupos me coge un sólo elemento como un único artículo y me imprime en pantalla un sólo grupo con el nombre de la colección que hay y como subelementos, osea botones, los elementos de la colección.

[image: Toma cómo elemento la colección y como sub elementos los elementos de la colección.]

De que forma puedo colocar la búsqueda(query) para que su resultado sean únicamente los elementos de la colección de forma tal que la iteración contenida en la iteración principal, la iteración de botones dentro de la iteración de grupo de botones, pueda ser impresa en pantalla correctamente?

Si no es posible hacerlo  a través de un query, entonces como puedo crear una lista con los subdocumentos de dicha colección?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depurando el código desde la consola de chrome he podido ver esto:
[image: Depurando node desde el navegador]

**Para poder preservar los mensajes de consola en el cliente es necesario activar la opción Preserve Log de la consola del navegador (sólo he visto esta opción en Chrome).**

Encontramos la función fecth:

> cursor.fetch() minimongo/minimongo.js, line 199
>
> Return all matching documents as an Array.
>
> When called from a reactive computation, fetch registers dependencies
>   on the matching documents.

El problema es donde usarlo, estoy usando meteor y si lo coloco por fuera del `helper`de la plantilla que lo usa entonces no funciona, para ello modificamos la función `helpers`de la plantilla:

```
Template.play_toolbar.helpers({
        group: function(){
            var main = Toolbars.find({name: 'main_toolbar'}, {items: 1, _id: 0}).fetch();
            console.log(main);
            return main[0].items
        },
        // group: music_toolbar,
        ifProgressBar: function (name) {
            return name === 'playback'
        }
    });
```

Si depuramos el código desde el navegador podemos notar que `main`es un objeto arreglo de objetos, y nuestro "query" únicamente trae un sólo objeto, sin embargo sigue siendo una lista de objetos, por lo cuál tenemos que obtener el objeto, para esto usamos su índice, que es 0, por tanto tomamos `main[0]`.

Pero si obtenemos ese elemento, sigue siendo un objeto, y nosotros queremos tener un arreglo de sub objetos, que corresponde a los subdocumentos de la colección. Los podemos obtener si vemos detenidamente que ese objeto tiene dentro una propiedad llamada elementos, donde está los sub objetos, por tanto llamamos a esa lista de objetos así: `main[0].items`.

El resultado obtenido es por fin el deseado:
[image: Barra de herramientas en la colección]

Es todo.